# ¿Antónimo de "ascender" en ámbitos civiles?

Tags: verbos, españa, solicitud-de-término, antónimos

Nos surgió ayer una pregunta en el trabajo con la que nos quedamos un poco dubitativos. La palabra *[ascender](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3vj12Rm)* significa "adelantar en empleo o dignidad" y "dar o conceder un ascenso". Sin embargo, no estamos muy seguro de qué palabra se usa en ámbitos empresariales para expresar lo contrario.

Las opciones que tenemos son:

- [**Degradar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C4T1Ot1). "Privar a alguien de las dignidades, honores, empleos y privilegios que tiene." Su uso nos parece más enfocado al ámbito militar, aunque no estamos seguros de si se usa también en la administración pública y la empresa privada.
- **Descender o bajar de categoría**.

Así pues, ¿cuál es el verbo antónimo a "ascender" en ámbitos empresariales civiles?

Comment: En política se suele _degradar_ a alguien. Aunque últimamente no sé yo si lo utilizan desde una perspectiva militar...

Comment: Al menos en teoría en Colombia está prohibido bajar de rango o categoría tanto a empleados públicos como privados por lo que ninguna palabra aplicaría :-) , pero concuerdo con @fedorqui en que _degradar_  (_disminuir en grado_) es lo que aplica perfectamente a lo que preguntas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mí me parece que **degradar** es la palabra que más se adecúa<sup>1</sup> y que entendería mejor en el contexto que mencionas.

Para ampliar el foco, y con la ayuda de la página de [sinónimos y antónimos de El País](http://servicios.elpais.com/diccionarios/sinonimos-antonimos/ascender) podemos pensar también en:

- **descender**: no por obvia tiene menos sentido. Sin embargo, parece más usada en ámbito deportivo.
- empeorar: no me convence en exceso, pues por ella sola es bastante genérica.
- [**relegar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VpnqvGc): suena bien, máxime viendo que su definición es *1. tr. Entre los antiguos romanos, desterrar a un ciudadano sin privarlo de los derechos de tal*. Básicamente, lo que vendría a ocurrir aquí: se mantiene en la empresa pero se le retiran los privilegios que tuviera. Y sí, estoy de acuerdo que no se pierden todos, sino algunos, por lo que tampoco es una opción óptima.
- [**defenestrar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C22zoYJ): esta es cosecha mía y considero que podría entenderse bien. Su definición es *Destituir o expulsar a alguien de un puesto, cargo, situación*, pero su simbolismo de "tirar ventana abajo" puede servir para explicar la degradación en la jerarquía de una empresa.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Curioso: para el presente del verbo [adecuar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0iArrmH) vale tanto *adecua* como *adecúa*</sub>